# Haskell - parse error on input "="

Tags: haskell

I have the following problem:

> ```
> We can cycle a list by a fixed amount by taking the given number of items off the front and adding them to the back of the list.
> Write a function called rotor so rotor 6 "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN" produces "GHIJKLMNABCDEF". Give the type as well as the definition for
> rotor. Make sure it returns an error message if the offset number is
> less than 0 or bigger than or equal to the length of the list.
> ```

And the following Haskell code:

```
rotor :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
rotor a (x:xs) 
  | if a < 1  = error "Error"
  | a [] = a []
  | otherwise = rotor a-1 xs ++ [x]
```

but when I compile it I get the following error:

> parse error on input "="

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Your `a-1` will need parentheses: `(a-1)`. Also, it is often a good idea to leave off the type signature for a function and use the `:type` command to have `ghci` tell you what the signature should be.

Comment: Read instructions carefully: The instruction says "number is less than 0", but the code reads `< 1`. Getting the edge cases right is important. BTW, I'd challenge that error requirement: As the word _rotor_ suggests, negative values corresponds to counter-rotation, and there is a fine solution for rotating more than one revolution (length of the list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rotor :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
rotor a (x:xs)
```

This line matches non-empty lists `x:xs`, only.

```
  | if a < 1  = error "Error"
```

No `if` is needed here.

```
  | a [] = a []
```

This should have been another pattern: after the `|` a boolean expression is expected.

An amended version of your code:

```
rotor :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
rotor a _      | a < 1 = error "Error"
rotor _ []             = []
rotor a (x:xs)         = rotor a-1 xs ++ [x]
```

This is not a correct solution, yet, since it does not satisfy your requirements, but it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

`if` in line 3 is not necessary. Guard expressions don't need it.